# Put quotation marks around each element of a vector, and separate with comma

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
> n <- 1:4
> n
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

I would like to transform `n` so that I get a string which is `'1', '2', '3', '4'` (which in `R`, would show as `"'1', '2', '3', '4'"`).

This often comes up when I'm using `sqlQuery()` with a variable string. I'm not familiar enough with RegEx to be able to perform this operation easily, unfortunately.

The closest I've gotten to is

```
> paste0(n, collapse = "", sep = ",")
[1] "1,2,3,4,"
```

which doesn't put the single quotations around each number and has the extra comma at the end.

Comment: `sep="','"` (note the extra `'`), and then put another set of `'` around the entire string you get: `"'" + paste0(...) + "'"`, basically

Comment: @nrussell Feel free to post that as an answer. I would appreciate, also, if you could explain what the `'%d'` means as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to use `sprintf` with `paste0`,

```
paste0(sprintf("'%d'", 1:4), collapse = ", ")
#[1] "'1', '2', '3', '4'"
```

where the `%d` is the standard formatting flag for signed integers from the C family of formatting functions (`printf`, `sprintf`, etc.). You can see the various options in the help file (`?sprintf`).

I prefer this to other alternatives because the `sprintf` call addresses the formatting of individual elements, while the `paste0(..., collapse = "<whatever>")` handles the combining of elements; your opinion may differ, though.

---

I frequently use `sprintf` & `cat`, in combination with `paste0` and other functions, when I need to generate redundant expressions to copy into SQL Server, or generate C++ macros, etc. For example, a bunch of `INSERT` statements

```
cat(sprintf("INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('%s', %d, %.2f);", 
            letters[1:5], 1:5, rnorm(5)), 
    sep = "\n"
)
#INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('a', 1, -1.10);
#INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('b', 2, 0.24);
#INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('c', 3, -0.82);
#INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('d', 4, -0.46);
#INSERT INTO #tmp(x, y, z) VALUES('e', 5, 0.72);
```